# composer update in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.2. and when I do composer update command on my CLI. it is generate following massages

Nothing to install or update
Generating Autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postupdate
>   php artisan optimize
>   Generating optimized class loader

cant i update my current version or is this an error I am new to Laravel

Answer (score 0):

This message is composer telling you that the package dependencies you have defined in your project are fully up-to date.

You could perhaps modify your `minimum-stability` level if you want to run things on the bleeding edge and currently have it set to `stable`.  Other possible values in order of decreasing stablity are `RC`, `beta`, `alpha`, and `dev`.  What you get from this is wholly package dependent, and you should keep in mind that package maintainers probably have a good reason for not releasing things as `stable`. I would caution against doing this on anything you may have running in a production environment.

See the [composer.json schema documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) for more information on `minimum-stablity`.

If you have dependencies defined in your `composer.json` that you believe aren't being pulled in and should be, please update your question with relevant portions from `composer.json` and identify what packages aren't installing.

Answer (score 0):

Like jeff said the package dependencies of your applications are up-to date , composer update is usually done when dependencies are added to the application and when you clone an application. I believe all your dependencies in **composer.json** are installed. Try to add a dependency of your application need and do `composer update`.